# Using distilled water on sterile swab for collecting microbes on solid surfaces

Tags: microbiology, lab-techniques

I was wondering if it is acceptable to use distilled water on a sterile swab for the collection of microbes on a solid surface. - in this case, Salmonella and Shigella.